# Angular fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, locale

I'm currently trying to add a localized version of `angular2-fullcalendar` into my project.
I'm using angular-cli and [angular2-fullcalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fullcalendar), which I installed using `npm install --save angular2-fullcalendar`.

Now for my question: The calendar component itself is working fine, I'm able to customize it and it shows all my events. 
The one thing I'm unable to achieve is localization. 
Following the docs of [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/) I'm required to add the locale *.js files, which I did by adding the file to my `angular-cli.json` file.
Unfortunately, this didn't lead to the expected result of an localized calendar.

Has anybody ever worked with `fullcalendar` in angular and could give me some pointers?
I'm relatively new to the angular business, so if I'm approaching things the totally wrong way, please also let me know! :)

Thank you!

Comment: What are the issues you are facing ? any error or locale file is not loading ?  Could you please check if moment js or locale file adding properly?

Comment: Post your `angular-cli.json` and some code. For what I can see in the documentation you only need to specify which locale you want.

Answer (score 0):

Open your angular-cli.json file, match file and replace the code :-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "project": {
     "name": "project name"
    },
   "apps": [
   {
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
       "assets",
       "favicon.ico"
      ],
     "index": "index.html",
     "main": "main.ts",
     "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
       ],
       "scripts": [
         "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
         "environments": {
           "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
         }
       }
     ],
    "e2e": {
       "protractor": {
        "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
     },
    "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
   ],
   "test": {
     "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
      }
     },
    "defaults": {
      "styleExt": "css",
      "component": {}
     }
    }
```